# assign one key of function output array to variable in tight away?

Tags: php, arrays, assign

I need to make following in one line, i am looking for method of making similar code one line not to solve this particular example.

```
$file_path = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
$file_name = $file_path["filename"];
```

e.g.

```
$file_name = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])["filename"];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is only possible from php 5.5. If you have an earlier version, sadly, it will not be possible.

However you could try using `list`, which will assign all the array elements in `pathinfo` to individual variables. If you order your variables correctly, `$file_name` will have what you need.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it is possible as of PHP5.5. I really appreciate this feature! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PHP's syntax does not support this for versions lower than PHP5.5. As of PHP5.5 you can just write:

```
echo pathinfo($path)['filename'];
```

If you are working with a version < 5.5, I would suggest to write a custom function:

```
function array_get($key, $array) {
    if(!array_kex_exists($key, $array)) {
        throw new Exception('$array has no index: ' . $key);
    }
    return $array[$key];
}
```

Then use it:

```
$filename = array_get('filename', pathinfo($path));
```